# Cannot return MAX value with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the matches of a competition of the next gameweek. A gameweek is when a match is played we can have these types of gameweeks: 20, 21, 22, 23. Each gameweek is played into a specific date. Now all the matches have a specific status, I can see if a match of a particular gameweek was played if the status value is 5, instead if is not played can have as status: 1, 2, 3, 4.

My query have this design:

```
 SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.datetime,
  CASE m.status
    WHEN 1 THEN 'scheduled'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'postponed'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'canceled'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'playing'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'finished'
  END AS match_status,
  m.gameweek, m.home_team_id, m.home_team_half_time_score, m.home_team_score,
  m.home_extra_time, m.home_penalties, m.away_team_id, m.away_team_half_time_score,
  m.away_team_score, m.away_extra_time, m.away_penalties, m.venue_id,
  m.venue_attendance, m.aggregate_match_id,
  t.name AS home_team_name,
  t_info.shield_link AS home_team_shield,
  t2.name AS away_team_name,
  t2_info.shield_link AS away_team_shield,
  c.name AS competition_name,
  c.id AS competition_id,
  r.name AS round_name
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN team_info t_info ON t.id = t_info.team_id
  LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN team_info t2_info ON t2.id = t2_info.team_id
  LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON m.round_id = r.id
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.id = s.competition_id
  WHERE 1 AND m.status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND m.round_id IN (10, 488, 392, 70)  
  AND m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m2.gameweek)
  FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id AND m2.status = m.status) 
  ORDER BY m.datetime DESC LIMIT 10
```

**Main Problem and Data structure**

main problem: the gameweek. I want return the next gameweek of the match already played, so suppose I have the following matches:

```
| id | round.id | status | gameweek | date
  1      488        5         1        1/07/2018
  2      488        5         1        1/07/2018
  3      488        5         1        1/07/2018
  4      488        1         2        7/07/2018
  5      488        1         2        7/07/2018
  6      488        1         2        7/07/2018
  7      488        1         3        16/07/2018
  8      488        1         3        16/07/2018
  9      488        1         3        16/07/2018
```

my query will return the matches id: 7, 8, 9. But should return instead: 4, 5, 6 because is the next gameweek that need to be played, the gameweek 1 has totally played.

Noticed that if there are almost one match that isn't played yet in the gameweek 1 for example, the query should return the gameweek 1 not the 2.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

**Additional further details**

in the first part of the query I select only the fields that I want return from the table joined. The selection is made using the main table match where all the matches are stored. I have the the join on the table team and team_info which takes the information of the two teams that play the match.

After this, I join the competition_rounds which get the details of the round, the round is simply an organization of the match, the same for the season, for example:

```
round.name = Regular Season | season.id = 5 season.name = 2017/2018 | id = 5
```

this doesn't really matter in this question but I'm trying to explain all the query activities.

In the where clause I get all the matches which have as status all the status available, that are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (you can find the status description in the query fields selector case). Later I have also a filter that return all the matches that are part of these rounds: 10, 488, 392, 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,played TINYINT NOT NULL
,gameweek INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,1,1),
(3,1,1),
(4,1,2),
(5,1,2),
(6,0,2),
(7,0,3),
(8,0,3),
(9,0,3);     

SELECT MIN(gameweek) gameweek FROM my_table WHERE played = 0;
+----------+
| gameweek |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
```

For the case where all games are played, I guess you could do something like this - although there's probably a more elegant solution...

```
UPDATE my_table SET played = 1;

SELECT COALESCE(y.gameweek,MAX(x.gameweek)) gameweek 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT MIN(gameweek) gameweek 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE played = 0 
     ) y
    ON y.gameweek = x.gameweek;
+----------+
| gameweek |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Seems to working but if all `matches` of all rounds are played the results will be empty, could you show me how to handle this in the same query? Thanks

Comment: In that event, what should the result be?

Comment: if all the `matches` of a round has played the query should return the last gameweek

Comment: I tried your query edit but I get: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contians nonaggregated column y.gameweek you could check my query here: pastebin.com/wgwAijFd

Answer (score 1):

Your where condition begins with `WHERE 1 AND m.status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

In my opinion `1 AND` is evaluated to `TRUE AND` and is not restricting your result - it is redundant. 
Same applies to condition `status in (1,2,3,4,5)` - if only that values can be set in status - as you explained.

The query which you executed: give me entries where the game week is euqal to the maximum game week which has an entry with same round_id and status.
So if an other game week exists with same status, the result is filtered to the last week of that status. In your special case, all matches in a week have same status.

The query which you want to execute: give me the minimum game week from the list of all game weeks with at leat one status entry <5.

So you want to filter out only the next game week, so you will use another subquery:

```
AND m.gameweek = (SELECT MIN(m2.gameweek) FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = m.round_id AND m2.status < 5 )
```